# Perl: When does "system" actually return?

Tags: perl, unix, cgi

In a CGI webpage, I have a button which when pressed submits a form and a subroutine is called which has:

```
sub run {
     &emailDebug("Started " .localtime);
    system("(/tools/script1.pl &) ; (/tools/script2.pl &)");
    &emailDebug("Ended " .localtime);
}
```

They both start at 11:08:05 (hence the fancy command), I take timestamps in the scripts themselves and send them in an email to myself.

The second finished 11:08:22 and the first 11:08:36 but the sent emails from above would show 11:08:06.

Most interestingly, the page is loading for about 30 seconds, as long as the longer of the two scripts run.

I don't mind the page loading but I don't understand why it behaves like this. As the 
page is loading, clearly the subroutine `run` itself doesn't return, but both emails are sent almost at the same time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`system` returns as soon as command that you call lets it to. In this particular example it should return immediately, but this may break depending on shell. To be extra sure you might try to just split call in two:

```
system("/tools/script1.pl &");
system("/tools/script2.pl &");
```

Also, depending on your web-server configuration, it may notice that you still have STDOUT open in forked childs and it will wait for all them to end before serving response, even if your main script is already ended. Redirect your spawned scripts STDOUT/ERR to /dev/null, `close(STDOUT)` and `close(STDERR)` in main script or consult your web-server/framework documentation on how to flush response when you're done with output.

Comment: Yes this must be it if I run the command on the system with my console as it is now (or yours) it goes in the bg but I have to press return to get my prompt back. Your setup behaves the same way incl the time behaviour. `close(STDOUT)` will kill the script as it has to print some html and close(STDERR) does nothing.

Comment: @Recc, set up forking manually then instead of using `system` and close OUT/ERR there.

Answer (score 2):

You are executing the scripts as background processes so system returns immediately. If you want to wait for completion then remove the `&`s and execute them sequentially:

```
system("(/tools/script1.pl) ; (/tools/script2.pl)");
```

Comment: Then why does the page load immediately as well? It still takes 30 odd seconds, that was my intent with the background processes because the other script also takes 15-20 sec when they run together It seems faster to the user.

Comment: This might be because of the resources used by your scripts.

Comment: Yes its the scripts taking that long (longest of the two as they start at the same time). System returns as you say indeed, but doesn't explain why the page still waits somehow, the sub finishes execution, I just checked by wrapping it with the same email calls.

Comment: if the script overloads your CPU, then the delay in page loading is expected.

Comment: These scripts execute on the server and the delay is because they're pulling thousands of records in XML across the net with some shitty API

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by *those print statements above*? Your code shows no `print` calls

Your `run` subroutine is returning as soon as the two child processes are started. You could make things clearer by making two calls to `system` and removing the parentheses in the command lines. Because of the trailing ampersand both calls to system will return immediately leaving the children to run independently

Something else must be delaying the return of the page after the call to `run`, and presumably it is somehow detecting when the work of the child processes is complete

By the way, you should *never* use an ampersand on a subroutine name when you are making a simple call. It hasn't been necessary since we got Perl 5 eighteen years ago

Comment: No there's nothing. I must've read outdated sources when I started with Perl didn't know about the &, cheers. (read some about it just now)